# Cannot migrate table using Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration, migrate

When I try to migrate tables I created I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Users' not found in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/
framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 301
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
"message":"Class 'Users' not found","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/laravel\/vendor
\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Migrations\/Migrator.php",
"line":301}}
```

Here is my code:

Users table:

```php
<?php

//Users Table
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(){
    }

}
```

Posts table:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('m_keyword');
            $table->string('m_disc');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
    }

}
```

http://laravel.io/bin/zj31n

Answer (score 0):

If you get the above error while running a migration,  please run the below command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

For more info, 
http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what has gone wrong is that you did not call

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

before

```
php artisan migrate
```

Try to force delete the tables and try to migrate again.

And another thing. The '**user_id**' column in the '**posts**' table should be connected to the users table like this:

```
Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

and I would call the create the table column like this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

or

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```